# Stop nginx from trimming file name in directory list?

Tags: nginx, configuration

Just a quick question:

How can I prevent nginx from trimming file name with ... in listing directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the only way to that is to edit the source code. The following *#define* in **src/http/modules/ngx_http_autoindex_module.c** have to be changed:

```
#define NGX_HTTP_AUTOINDEX_NAME_LEN     50
```

Maybe something else needs to be tweaked too, but that's what I saw at first glance.

Comment: This could be time consuming. You sure there is no other way around this? If not I could start write a small php script.

Comment: There's no other way, maximal length is hard-coded with the *#define* above. Yep, external script for directory listing may be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert, but in nginx one can do this:

```
fancyindex_name_length 255;
```

Where 255, obviously, is a max length to trim to you want to achieve.

Works fine in nginx 1.18.0 on Debian with `libnginx-mod-http-fancyindex`

More docs: https://github.com/aperezdc/ngx-fancyindex#fancyindex-name-length

Answer (score 0):

i use Fancy Index module (ubuntu: libnginx-mod-http-fancyindex) and specify simple file with this js snippet.

```
location / {
    fancyindex on;
    fancyindex_footer footer.html;
    fancyindex_ignore footer.html;
}
```

```js
<!-- footer.html in the folder -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("a").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).attr('href'))
})
</script>
```